# how to check if null value in single line

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, ado

I am getting a value from db, and when the value is **NULL** I get an error

> Could not convert variant of type (null) into type (Integer)

If I fill in the db with **0** instead of nothing (**NULL**) the error goes away

So say I have this

```
  OneSpell.PerCent     :=              FQuery.Recordset.Fields[ DB_FLD_PER_CENT    ].Value;
  OneSpell.Plus        := TCardPlus  ( FQuery.Recordset.Fields[ DB_FLD_PLUS        ].Value );
  OneSpell.Quantity    :=              FQuery.Recordset.Fields[ DB_FLD_QUANTITY    ].Value;
```

is there a way to say if the value is **NULL** then make it **0**? Or does this have to be done via the db.

`FQuery` is an `adoquery` and db is access

I know I could do

```
if  .... = null then 
  onespell.plus := 0 
else
   .........
```

But I want to do it in one line for each value of onespell

Comment: What is `OneSpell`? What type are `PerCent`, `Plus`, and `Quantity`? Is `FQuery` a `TADOQuery`, or something else? Can you be somewhat more specific, so we can try and help you? (And yes, if you want 0 instead of NULL, the easiest solution to reduce the code is to do it in the SQL itself using `IsNull()` or `Coalesce()` or whatever the equivalent is in whatever unspecified database system you're using, because then your application code doesn't need to worry about what is being returned - it knows it will be a valid numeric value.)

Comment: @kenWhite well it was hard to explain what exactly onespell is, but the type for percent, plus and quantity should be an integer. the db is huge and going threw and putting all 0 would take some time. and if its null the percent, plus, quantity is not used thus i figured 0 to compress the error.  I was hopeing for a way to add if statement in one line something like this `oneSpell.plus := if(null)then 0 else .... `  but thought there was a way to do this  yes its an adoquery , using access db. but would rather do it in these lines of code if possable...once agian huge db..

Comment: Once again, what is `FQuery`? Is it a `TADOQuery`? (It makes a difference, because what's available for use varies depending on the class. Also, if it is a `TADOQuery`, are there really multiple recordsets? If not, there's no need to use `FQuery.RecordSet`, which makes it easier.)

Comment: @KenWhite sorry i added it to last comment but prob after you read it, but yes FQuery is a TADOQuery, and yes there is multiple recordsets.  like in some code you can do it quicker with a ? and keep it all in the same line

Comment: As I said in my last comment, [edit] the question and add that information **there**, instead of burying it in the comments.

Comment: updated, you would think an inline if statement would not care.

Comment: It cares, because some types of query support `IsNull`, and some (like `TADOQuery`) don't. `TADOQuery.Recordset` supports even fewer options, because it's a raw ADO Recordset and doesn't have the Delphi wrapper methods to hide some of the complexity (which is why I asked the question in the first place). The [docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.Recordset) specifically says not to use `Recordset` if you can avoid it for that reason.

Comment: @KenWhite assumeing i can NOT avoid it, how can i do this?  and If i could avoid it how could i do it?  Ill have to check back threw code to see if its needed.

Comment: I have no idea how you can avoid it, because you've not explained why your query has multiple recordsets in the first place. Most SQL queries don't return more than one, unless you're using a `TADOCommand` instead to execute a series of `SELECT` statements in one script. (I'm presuming that you're aware that multiple **recordsets** are not the same as multiple **records** (rows).)

Comment: @kenWhite The honest answer is that I don't know. I had no particular reason to use recordset. Actually that isn't quite true. There was a reason why I did it that way but it can't have been important because I don't remember it now.

Comment: Glen, the only reason I would accept is performance. If you're fetching just one recordset, there is no need to use access through `Recordset` in this case. Yes, it might be faster since it provides you a direct access to the ADO recordset interface but I doubt you'd notice the difference. If you'll decide to use access without `Recordset`, then typecasting to numeric types will return 0 when the value is `NULL` (for instance `FQuery.Fields[DB_FLD_PER_CENT].AsFloat` returns 0 when its value is `NULL`).

Comment: @TLama: Exactly, which is why I asked in the first place. :-)

Comment: @kenwhite I would post a link to my spells unit but its over 1200 lines of code.  I am  trying to remember why i choose to use recordset I may of used it as an "incase" as i have multiple queries at a time, But i will update once i remember why lol.. any how thanks for all answers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is the common way to go:

Extract the repeating parts to keep the code DRY and to increase readability

```
function IfNull( const Value, Default : OleVariant ) : OleVariant;
begin
  if Value = NULL then
    Result := Default
  else
    Result := Value;
end;

...
OneSpell.Plus := IfNull( FQuery.Recordset.Fields[ DB_FLD_PER_CENT].Value, 0 );
```

Comment: +1, because I failed to continue to the logical conclusion in my own answer - I stopped one level short. :$

Comment: @SirRufo at `if value = NULL then` i get error that NULL is not defined.

Answer (score 7):

Because you're using the `ADOQuery.Recordset`, which returns a reference to the underlying `_Recordset` (which is not from Delphi, but is an ADO object reference directly), your choices are limited to those that ADO directly support. Delphi's `TADOQuery` has wrapper methods that hide a lot of the complexity of dealing with ADO at a lower level, and using a `Recordset` instead severely limits your options.

AFAICT, the only way to do it in one line would be using a *long line* that utilizes both the `VarIsNull` function and the [`Math.IfThen`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Math.IfThen) function (which defaults to `0` if you omit the `AFalse` paremeter):

```
OneSpell.PerCent := IfThen(not VarIsNull(FQuery.Recordset.Fields[ DB_FLD_PER_CENT].Value), FQuery.Recordset.Fields[DB_FLD_PER_CENT].Value);
```

You can do it in two lines more readably with an intermediate `OleVariant` variable (still requiring the `Math` unit):

```
var
  Val: OleVariant;
...
  Val := FQuery.Recordset.Fields[DB_FLD_PER_CENT].Value;
  OneSpell.PerCent := IfThen(not VarIsNull(Val), Val);
```

The easiest alternative (from a Delphi code standpoint, anyway) would be to handle this in your SQL statement itself, using `IsNull` or `Coalesce` or its equivalent in MS Access, so you don't have to worry about it in your application code;  you can simply access the `Value` and know it contains an integer instead.

Actually, the **easiest** alternative is not to use `RecordSet` at all if you don't actually need to do so (because there are multiple recordsets in your `TADOCommand` results). If you simply use Delphi's `TADOQuery` directly, you can simply use the native `TField.AsXXX` properties, which will handle the conversions for you automatically:

```
OneSpell.PerCent := FQuery.Fields[DB_FLD_PER_CENT].AsInteger; // Or AsFloat
```

Comment: I think this is a great answer, and using `.AsInteger`  would be easiest.  but untill i can remember why i used recordset.. i will go the route using math unit

Answer (score 4):

Stop doing the work in delphi code, your query should handle this. Most DB backends support the [COALESCE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COALESCE#COALESCE) function. So in your query, just use : `SELECT COALESCE(MyIntegerField, 0) FROM Foo`. If `MyIntegerField` contains a `NULL` value, `COALESCE` will return the first `non-NULL` value, in this case `0`

**EDIT**

Just realized that your DB backend is MS Access, in that case use the `IIF` function:

```
SELECT Percent= IIf([Percent] Is Null, 0, [Percent]) FROM Foo
```

Comment: This only would not work when fields are Aggregated or Calculated fields.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that you will always want the Null interpreted as a false Boolean, 0 numeric value, or empty string, you can set [System.Variants.NullStrictConvert](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Variants.NullStrictConvert) = false.

(Strictly speaking, for the Null to string conversion the value of [System.Variants.NullAsStringValue](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Variants.NullAsStringValue) will be taken).

Answer (score 2):

Would try to show two more variants, that are going out of the box somewhat.

1: use TDataSet native access

```
OneSpell.Plus := TCardPlus  ( FQuery.FieldByName( 'DB_FLD_PLUS' ).AsInteger );
```

or

```
OneSpell.Plus := TCardPlus  ( FQuery.Fields[ 2 ].AsInteger );
```

assuming "DB_FLD_PLUS" was a third column in your query. `TField.AsInteger` returns zero for empty (NULL) columns.

2: use Delphi advanced records

```
type 
   TSpellPlus = record
       Value : TCardPlus;
       class operator Implicit( const from: TCardPlus ):  TSpellPlus; inline;
       class operator Implicit( const from: Variant ):    TSpellPlus;
       class operator Implicit( const from: TSpellPlus ): TCardPlus;  inline;
   end;

   TOneSpell = record
     private
       function GetCardPlus: TCardPlus; inline;
       procedure SetCardPlus( const Value: TCardPlus ); inline;
     public   
       var PerCent : integer;  
       var PlusVar : TSpellPlus;
       property Plus : TCardPlus read GetCardPlus write SetCardPlus;
       var Quantity : cardinal;
   end;

 function TOneSpell.GetCardPlus: TCardPlus;
 begin
    Result := Self.PlusVar;
 end;

 procedure TOneSpell.SetCardPlus( const Value: TCardPlus );
 begin
    Self.PlusVar := Value;
 end;

 class operator TSpellPlus.Implicit( const from: TSpellPlus ): TCardPlus;
 begin
    Result := From.Value; 
 end;

 class operator TSpellPlus.Implicit( const from: TCardPlus ):  TSpellPlus;
 begin
    Result.Value := From;
 end;

 class operator TSpellPlus.Implicit( const from: Variant ):    TSpellPlus;
 var i: integer;
 begin
    if VarIsNull( From )
       then i := 0 
       else i := From;
    Result.Value := TCardPlus( i );
 end;


   ....

 OneSpell.PlusVar := FQuery.Recordset.Fields[ DB_FLD_PLUS        ].Value;
```

Then those three lines would be equivalent:

```
var cp: TCardPlus;

cp := OneSpell.Plus;
cp := OneSpell.PlusVar;
cp := OneSpell.PlusVar.Value;
```

Comment: The `As<Type>` casting would be the best for `TCustomADODataSet` descendants since numeric typecasting returns 0 if the underlying field is `NULL`. The problem is that OP is not accessing ADO dataset, but ADO recordset, whose fields are of [`Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677568(v=vs.85).aspx) type and values are returned as `OleVariant`.

Comment: @tlama plz do not use angular brackets: I had tough minutes trying to figure out where to use generics here :-D  Since the dataset is a wrapper over recordset, what would be a problem reading that particular column via TField?

Comment: Sorry for that :-) I've copied it from my deleted answer. Well, it depends on the real purpose of the recordset access used here. It might be due to performance reasons (since it provides reference to the ADO recordset interface), or maybe just a mistake. Or just a showcase for accessing next datasets (declared as variables) fetched through the [`NextRecordset`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.NextRecordset) method. Hard to say. If it's by mistake, that `AsType` casting would IMHO be the most elegant way (it would add type safety as well).

Answer (score 1):

Interesting Post and interesting answers, anyhow, what was not mentioned, at least clearly throughout all the answers, and might seem very obvious, but not so much for newcomers on Delphi/Firedac is that you need to include (Add to the uses of the module) the interface SYSTEM.VARIANTS in order to ask if a datafield.value = NULL or <> NULL.